# String value Error in mysql with utf8 encoding

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, encoding, hikaricp

i am using scala with ScalikeJDBC, my table encoding is utf8mb4 with utf8mb4_general_ci collection ,i  get:

```
03/01/2015 08:40:57 - ERROR[http-apr-8080-exec-9] StatementExecutor$$anon$1 - SQL execution failed (Reason: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A' for column 'body' at row 81):
```

Even though my data source code is:

```
val dataSource: DataSource = {
    val ds = new HikariDataSource()
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://" + org.Server.GlobalSettings.DB.mySQLIP + ":3306?rewriteBatchedStatements=true")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", "SOMEUSER")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", "SomePassword")
    ds.setAutoCommit(false) // dosne't work

    ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode", "yes")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding", "utf8")
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("connectionCollation", "utf8_unicode_ci")

    //      ds.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding", "utf8mb4") //dosne't work either
    //      ds.addDataSourceProperty("connectionCollation", "utf8mb4_unicode_ci")//dosne't work either
    ds
  }
```

For the body column i do:

```
 try{
    .
    .
    .
        body = new String(rev.body.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8") 
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

No exception caught, but still on query commit it failed on: '' Incorrect string value: ... for column 'body' '', time and time again, can anybody help me ?

Answer (score -1):

Make you encoding as UTF-8:

```
body = new String(rev.body.getBytes("utf-8"), "UTF-8")
```

Or use `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: Doing this makes no sense at all. You have a Java string, get the bytes for a specific encoding and then create a new string from those bytes using the same encoding. The end result is the same string value.